# Sending xAPI statement to a web application instead of LRS

Tags: xapi

I have an xAPI content made by storyline I want for the statement to be sent to a webapp instead of the LRS.
this webapp is developped using laravel, and user should be authenticated with email and password to use it.
what I did to send the statement to this app:

1.in the webapp I created an API endpoint route that use POST method.

2.in the xAPI wrapper I changed the endpoint in the configuration to the route I made in the webapp.

```
const conf = {
        "endpoint":"here I added my api endpoint route of the webapp",
        "auth":"Basic " + toBase64(""),
    }
```

now whith any interaction with the content where a statement should be sent the request making cors error like in the picture down, I think this is authentication error, how can I add my authentication credentials to the xAPI wrapper?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your non-LRS LRS is probably not handling preflight requests which are necessary for CORS handling. Most common LRSs will handle those requests appropriately since they expect to be accessed from additional origins. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

Also note that you'll likely run into issues unless you also handle state requests.

Additionally unless you are requesting the credentials from the user during runtime then hard coding the credentials into the package isn't a great idea from a security perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I asked the user to enter his credentials at the beginning of the content, How would I add/integrate those credentials to the xAPI wrapper dynamically? what options do I have to do it the right way

Comment: See the "Create your own configuration object and pass it to the xapiwrapper object
" section of https://github.com/adlnet/xAPIWrapper#configuration